# Using put on SnowSQL to stage a CSV file results in Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Object'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying out Snowflake, and am attempting to `put` a CSV file onto a stage using SnowSQL. Whenever I do so, I get the following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Object'.

This doesn't happen with other CSVs I have tried to stage. I can't find anything about this Googling. I honestly don't even know where to start. I've tried different methods of dealing with NULL fields when exporting my data to CSV in case that was part of the problem, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Any ideas of what could be wrong or what I should try?

Comment: Please add to your question the full PUT command you are using and the full error message

Comment: It was just a simple put command: `put file:///<path_to_file>.csv @stage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand there's been some issues with the very latest version of SnowSQL. If you run this (instead of just "snowsql") before the rest of your commands, it will force this version instead:

snowsql -v 1.2.12

If this works, then you know it's related to the version issue and you can use this to workaround until it's updated with a fix.

Comment: This was the issue! Thank you so much for the quick response and workaround. (And that makes sense as to why I couldn't find any information about the error.)

Comment: Ok, cool!  Yes, seems to be a very recent issue that will hopefully get fixed soon.